# Java input parser for integers not working

Tags: java, input, encoding, char, decoding

I am playing around with parsing integers. I feed my program a line of integers. Remove all whitespace. Then The logic is this:

```
If I get a 0, 
   If the next char is 1, 
      Print out a 0
   If the next char is 0,
      Print out a 1
   Forget the 2 chars I just checked
If I get a 1, 
   If the next char is 0, 
      Print out a 1
   If the next char is 1,
      print out a 0
   Forget the 2 chars I just checked
```

So an input of 10100 1011011 00, I should get 1100101. This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Blah {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = input.nextLine();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == '0') {
                if (text.charAt(i++) == '1') {
                    System.out.print("0");
                } else if (text.charAt(i++) == '0') {
                    System.out.print("1");
                }
                if (i < text.length()) 
                     i++;
            } else {
                if (text.charAt(i++) == '0') {
                    System.out.print("1");
                    i++;
                } else if (text.charAt(i++) == '1') {
                    System.out.print("0");
                }
                if (i < text.length()) 
                      i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this is not giving me the expected result. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What result _is_ it giving you? Why is it giving you that result (what did debugging the code reveal)?

Comment: I think you've made a mistake about the exact behavior of `i++` - I don't think you want to increment twice if your first conditional isn't true.  Also, I think you want to do `++i` if anything.

Comment: For once thing, my 01 is converting to 1 instead of 0 @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Also the code to take out all the whitespace is not working @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your increment to be `i+=2` and remove the other places `i` is incremented. Also use `i+1` for checking the next char, not `i++`. Use a regex expression to get rid of all the whitespace before entering your loop.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = input.nextLine();
text=text.replaceAll("\\s+","");
int i;
for (i = 0; i < text.length()-1; i+=2) {
   if (text.charAt(i) == '0') {
      if (text.charAt(i+1) == '1') 
         System.out.print("0");
       else if (text.charAt(i+1) == '0') {
         System.out.print("1");
    } else {
       if (text.charAt(i+1) == '0') 
         System.out.print("1");
       else if (text.charAt(i+1) == '1') 
         System.out.print("0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `i+1` or `++i` instead of `i++` because that means it will use the current value and then increment `i`, instead of your desired behavior of getting the next value.

EDIT: Updated to show changes in code

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == '0') {
        if (text.charAt(++i) == '1') {
            System.out.print("0");
        } else if (text.charAt(++i) == '0') {
            System.out.print("1");
        }
        if (i < text.length()) {
            i++;
        } 
    } else {
        if (text.charAt(++1) == '0') {
            System.out.print("1");
            i++;
        } else if (text.charAt(++i) == '1') {
            System.out.print("0");
        }
        if (i < text.length()) {
                  i++;
        }
    }
}
```